# splitting name and id

Tags: php, regex

I have a string

> "JonSmith02-11-1955"

I use
`preg_split` to get JonSmith (reg='[0-9-]') then do it again ('[a-zA-Z]\ ') to get his birthdate.
Is there any better way to get them both in one split ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)/i
```

works in this case. It matches a position preceded by a letter and followed by a digit. Read about [lookbehinds and -aheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more information.

This won't work if the name can contain digits.

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/oyBKSfZo)

Answer (score 2):

What about `^(.*)(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{4})$`?
It will parse your string into four parts: `JonSmith`, `02`, `11` and `1955`.

Comment: This is probably the best solution in terms of robustness. You should mention that it should be used together with `preg_match`. And instead of creating a capture group for each number, you might want to group the whole date.

Answer (score 1):

```
^([a-zA-z]*)([0-9]*)\-(.+)*$
```

For this example :

```
JonSmith02-11-1955
```

Give :

```
JonSmith
02
11-1955
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `/(\w*)(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/` as your regex - someone else can probably do that more efficiently. This will give you two capturing groups, so

```
$array = preg_match_all('/(\w*)(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/', "JonSmith02-11-1955");
print_r($array); 
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => JonSmith02-11-1955
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => JonSmith
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02-11-1955
        )

)

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/([a-z]+)([0-9-]+)/i', 'JonSmith02-11-1955', $matches);
echo "Name is $matches[1]<br>\n";
echo "Birth date is $matches[2]<br>\n";
```

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/d0avrh)